# Is there any sort of "pre login" event or similar?

Tags: php, symfony

I need to run some code prior to checking if a user's credentials are correct. Currently I'm achieving this with a custom event listener that fires on the `kernel.request` event and checks if the requested URL matches security.yml's `check_path` setting. But this is inefficient since it runs on every request. I'm aware of the `onSecurityInteractiveLogin` event, but I believe that fires after a successful login attempt.  Does anyone know if there's a pre login event, or where I could dispatch a custom event myself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, there's no 'official' pre-login event. But thankfully it's not hard to set one up since Symfony2 is so extendable. The trick is to use your own service to handle authentication.

Symfony uses this class when using a login form:

`Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener`

If you override the `security.authentication.listener.form.class` parameter (originally defined in `Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Resources\config\security_listeners.xml`) you can use a custom listener that extends `UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener`.

All that's left to do is override the `attemptAuthentication()` method to dispatch the custom event.

(Actually you also need to store the event dispatcher as a class property in `__construct()`)

This method should work with other authentication methods - all you'd need to do is modify the appropriate listener (ie `BasicAuthenticationListener`, `X509AuthenticationListener`, etc.)

Comment: can you please provide some example since i do not know where to start.

Comment: I implemented this suggestion with these steps: 1) add a line "security.authentication.listener.form.class: App\BoardBundle\Listener\MyAuthListener" into your config.yml, parameters section 2) actually create this class class MyAuthListener extends UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener { 3) in it, create protected function attemptAuthentication(Request $request)