# Adding Captcha to Symfony2 Login Page

Tags: symfony, authentication, captcha, fosuserbundle

I am new to Symfony2 but read about it very much.
First of all, I am using symfony 2.1.7. And FOSUserBundle for user settings. I have already override fos_user-login template, with username and password. But I want to add a captcha for log in. I have seen GregwarCaptchaBundle, and according to document, new field should be added to FormType. And my question comes: Where is the symfony or FOSUserBundle login form type, that i can add this new field, or override it? There exists ChangePasswordFormType, ProfileFormType... etc. but no LoginFOrmType. May be it is so obvious but i did not get the point, Any help is welcomed please
**QUESTION IS EDITED WITH A SOLUTION SOMEHOW**
Take a look at the comments below that Patt helped me.
I have created a new form type with `_username`, `_password` and `captcha` fields. When naming for username and password begins with an underscore is enough for 'login_check' routing and Symfony authentication. However Symfony uses a listener for login process.
Which is `UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener`class. Although i've added captcha field in the Form type, it is always ignored during login process.(It is rendered on the page, but the field is never validated, it is simply ignored.)

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('_username', 'email', array('label' => 'form.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle')) // TODO: user can login with email by inhibit the user to enter username
        ->add('_password', 'password', array(
        'label' => 'form.current_password',
        'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
        'mapped' => false,
        'constraints' => new UserPassword()))
        ->add('captcha', 'captcha');
}
```

As i mentioned above `UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener` class gets the form input values and then redirects you:

```
public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext, AuthenticationManagerInterface $authenticationManager, SessionAuthenticationStrategyInterface $sessionStrategy, HttpUtils $httpUtils, $providerKey, AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface $successHandler, AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface $failureHandler, array $options = array(), LoggerInterface $logger = null, EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher = null, CsrfProviderInterface $csrfProvider = null)
{
    parent::__construct($securityContext, $authenticationManager, $sessionStrategy, $httpUtils, $providerKey, $successHandler, $failureHandler, array_merge(array(
        'username_parameter' => '_username',
        'password_parameter' => '_password',
        'csrf_parameter'     => '_csrf_token',
        'captcha'           => 'captcha',
        'intention'          => 'authenticate',
        'post_only'          => true,
    ), $options), $logger, $dispatcher);

    $this->csrfProvider = $csrfProvider;
}
```

captcha field is added.

```
protected function attemptAuthentication(Request $request)
{
    if ($this->options['post_only'] && 'post' !== strtolower($request->getMethod())) {
        if (null !== $this->logger) {
            $this->logger->debug(sprintf('Authentication method not supported: %s.', $request->getMethod()));
        }

        return null;
    }

    if (null !== $this->csrfProvider) {
        $csrfToken = $request->get($this->options['csrf_parameter'], null, true);

        if (false === $this->csrfProvider->isCsrfTokenValid($this->options['intention'], $csrfToken)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException('Invalid CSRF token.');
        }
    }

   // check here the captcha value
    $userCaptcha = $request->get($this->options['captcha'], null, true);
    $dummy = $request->getSession()->get('gcb_captcha');
    $sessionCaptcha = $dummy['phrase'];
   // if captcha is not correct, throw exception
    if ($userCaptcha !== $sessionCaptcha) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException('Captcha is invalid');
    }

    $username = trim($request->get($this->options['username_parameter'], null, true));
    $password = $request->get($this->options['password_parameter'], null, true);

    $request->getSession()->set(SecurityContextInterface::LAST_USERNAME, $username);

    return $this->authenticationManager->authenticate(new UsernamePasswordToken($username, $password, $this->providerKey));
}
```

Now, i have captcha on login screen.
Playing with symfony code is not a good way, i know. If i find out some way to override and call my own function, i'll post it.
**ANOTHER USEFUL ANSWER**

I found another answer that might be useful
[link][Is there any sort of "pre login" event or similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406001/is-there-any-sort-of-pre-login-event-or-similar?answertab=active#tab-top)

Following this solution, I have simply override `UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener`class and override security listener `security.authentication.listener.form.class` parameter. Here goes the code:

```
namespace TCAT\StaffBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener as BaseListener; use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Csrf\CsrfProvider\CsrfProviderInterface; use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request; use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\LoggerInterface; use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface; use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface; use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Session\SessionAuthenticationStrategyInterface; use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\HttpUtils; use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationManagerInterface; use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken; use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException; use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface; use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface; use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;


    class StaffLoginFormListener extends BaseListener
    {
        private $csrfProvider;

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext, AuthenticationManagerInterface $authenticationManager, SessionAuthenticationStrategyInterface $sessionStrategy, HttpUtils $httpUtils, $providerKey, AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface $successHandler, AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface $failureHandler, array $options
= array(), LoggerInterface $logger = null, EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher = null, CsrfProviderInterface $csrfProvider = null)
        {
            parent::__construct($securityContext, $authenticationManager, $sessionStrategy, $httpUtils, $providerKey, $successHandler, $failureHandler, array_merge(array(
                'username_parameter' => '_username',
                'password_parameter' => '_password',
                'csrf_parameter'     => '_csrf_token',
                'captcha'           => 'captcha',
                'intention'          => 'authenticate',
                'post_only'          => true,
            ), $options), $logger, $dispatcher);

            $this->csrfProvider = $csrfProvider;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        protected function attemptAuthentication(Request $request)
        {
            if ($this->options['post_only'] && 'post' !== strtolower($request->getMethod())) {
                if (null !== $this->logger) {
                    $this->logger->debug(sprintf('Authentication method not supported: %s.', $request->getMethod()));
                }

                return null;
            }

            if (null !== $this->csrfProvider) {
                $csrfToken = $request->get($this->options['csrf_parameter'], null, true);

                if (false === $this->csrfProvider->isCsrfTokenValid($this->options['intention'], $csrfToken)) {
                    throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException('Invalid CSRF token.');
                }
            }

            // throw new BadCredentialsException('Bad credentials');
            $userCaptcha = $request->get($this->options['captcha'], null, true);
            $dummy = $request->getSession()->get('gcb_captcha');
            $sessionCaptcha = $dummy['phrase'];

            if ($userCaptcha !== $sessionCaptcha) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException('Captcha is invalid');
            }

            $username = trim($request->get($this->options['username_parameter'], null, true));
            $password = $request->get($this->options['password_parameter'], null, true);

            $request->getSession()->set(SecurityContextInterface::LAST_USERNAME, $username);

            return $this->authenticationManager->authenticate(new UsernamePasswordToken($username, $password, $this->providerKey));
        }



    }
```

and add `security.authentication.listener.form.class:      TCAT\StaffBundle\Listener\StaffLoginFormListener` line to the app/config/paramaters.yml
BTW i can check my captcha value. I hope it all work for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Adding Captcha to Symfony2 Login Page
```

I am not sure this is a great idea. But it's doable.

```
Where is the symfony or FOSUserBundle login form type?
```

There is no form type for the login. The form is directly embed in the template as you can see in [login.html.twig](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig#L1-L22).

```
How could you do it?
```

You could totally create one but you would have to customize the [SecurityController](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php) so that you send your form to the template.

---

**The procedure would be something like that:**

<kbd>**1.**</kbd> Create your custom `loginFormType` (that's where you can add your captcha in the builder).

<kbd>**2.**</kbd> Override the `SecurityController` (you could take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790113/dynamically-styling-an-fos-userbundle-login-page/14796887#14796887) to see something similar). You need to override the `loginAction` method so that you can pass the form to your template [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php#L44-48).

<kbd>**3.**</kbd> Override `login.html.twig` to render the form passed from your controller

---

### Edit: Answer to your comment

> How can you access to your form in a controller that extends
>   ContainerAware?

I highly recommend [this reading](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/06/14/symfony2-moving-away-from-the-base-controller/) to see how you can move away from the base controller. Now, how can you do this?

Well, you have 2 options:

### OPTION 1: EASY WAY

```
$form = $this->createForm(new LoginFormType(), null);
```

becomes:

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new LoginFormType(), $null);
```

### OPTION 2: REGISTER FORM AS A SERVICE

<kbd>**1.**</kbd> Create your formType (normal procedure): `loginFormType`

<kbd>**2.**</kbd> Define your form as a service `acme_user.login.form`. You have a great example [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.2.x/Resources/config/registration.xml#L9-L21) (In the 1.2 version of FOSUserBundle, both registration and profile forms were registered as services, so this gives you a perfect example of how it's done).

<kbd>**3.**</kbd> You can now use your form inside your controller extending ContainerAware. See [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.2.x/Controller/RegistrationController.php#L33).

```
$form = $this->container->get('acme_user.login.form');
```

Comment: Hi @Patt, I would ask a few things: Say that I created a LoginFormType, and want to override SecurityController in order to overrride loginAction for passing my form. But In securityController, how would i create my form, and pass it? Since SecurityController is extended from ContainerAware ?

Comment: Things are getting more interesting, those were the good days with sf1.4 and pretty much easier...

Comment: Very good question actually. You can define your form as a service. I have updated my question. Good luck!

Comment: I have created the form by option 1. It worked, and my defined form displayed with the Capthca. This is the good news. Now we can move one step forward: Where should i check the value of captcha? The standard login_check checks the _username and _password. I can login the firewall independent of the captcha value. As i told before i use GenemuFormBundle GD for captcha. Thank you so much @Patt. I have some vision about overriding with you :)

Comment: The bundle you are using should take care of this on its own if you simply add the captcha in the builder. If it doesn't, you'd have to read the doc on the bundle you're using. Otherwise, You can use the [GregwarCaptchaBundle](http://www.knpbundles.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle) and validation is handled automatically.

Comment: Yes i simply add captcha to the builder ->add('')... And i see the captcha image and the field, but its value is not checked, i simply login whatever the value of the captcha is. But now i try GregwarCaptchaBundle. I tell you the results @Patt

Comment: The same result occured with GregwarCaptcha. Captcha is rendered but it is not take into account while authentication. It is rendered as a required field and you have to enter a few chacacters for field, but the values are ignored somehow and i can login with my email and password (Since i changed username to email in form). I do not really know what is the problem, but login_check route is somewhere in the system and it is not aware of captcha i guess. What should we do @Patt

Comment: Very hard to tell without the code. I think this would be the subject of an other question. If I were you, I would open an other question, where you can put your code so that we can help. You.ll need to deep into validation and see why the captcha validation is not triggered.

Comment: thank you so much, i will ask the question later on, and post question here. But I made some debug on the code and found out that: UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener() class is the responsible class for login as i guess and it is designed for login pages with two field only (_username and _password) If we add a third param as captcha to the constructor of this class, we can access user input captcha and check it with the value in session.

Comment: Good to know. You can totally ask this into an other question. Would be good to see what other people think. Good luck.

Comment: As i said previously, I have added captcha option to __construct() of UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener class. At attemptAuthentication() function, i checked the captcha and give an exception if captcha is wrong. And it works now. I will only override this class on my own, due to updates in vendor. Thanks for help @Patt, I appreciate you

Comment: Awesome! Well, you did all the work. Didn't know about the UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener, I'll look it up. Thanks for that!

Comment: Just a tip, people might be interested to see how you did this inside the listener. You can edit your question by adding EDIT at the end of your question and then put some code that explains how you solved the problem. No need to put 1000 lines (better not to actually), but this will allow people to see what you've done and also upvote your question. Just a suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

**In response to : Playing with symfony code is not a good way, i know. If i find out some way to override and call my own function, i'll post it.**

To override the "UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListenerclass" you must copy the listner file in your bundle and change the config.yml file to load th new one :

```
parameters:
        security.authentication.listener.form.class: Acme\YourBundle\Security\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener
```

Also the namespace in the copied file must be changed to the correct one :

```
namespace Acme\YourBundle\Security;
```

The last thing is adding "AbstractAuthenticationListener" in the use part  to be loaded correctly :

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AbstractAuthenticationListener;
```