# How to implement Recaptcha in login form in symfony2 and Recaptcha should show after three wrong login attempt?

Tags: symfony

I have been trying to show recaptcha on login page after three wrong login attempt but could not get the exact idea.

As i gone through these following links

1. [adding-captcha-to-symfony2-login-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788828/adding-captcha-to-symfony2-login-page)
2. [dynamically-styling-an-fos-userbundle-login-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790113/dynamically-styling-an-fos-userbundle-login-page/14796887#14796887)
3. [reference-security-firewall-form-login](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#reference-security-firewall-form-login)
4. [is-there-any-sort-of-pre-login-event-or-similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406001/is-there-any-sort-of-pre-login-event-or-similar?answertab=active#tab-top)

How to do without any external bundle. As i work in symfony2 based projects, But this login is kind of tricky for me.

**EDIT**

FYI, I created LoginType in bundle and update security.yml file.
**LoginType.php**

```
class LoginType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username','text')
            ->add('password','password')
            ->add('recaptcha', 'ewz_recaptcha', array(
                    'attr' => array(
                        'options' => array(
                            'theme' => 'white'
                        )
                    ),
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'constraints'   => array(
                        new True
                    )
                )
            )
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'intention' => 'authentication'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'login';
    }
}
```

**Security.yml**

```
    username_parameter: "login[username]"
    password_parameter: "login[password]"
    csrf_parameter: "login[_token]"
    csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
    intention: authentication                 
    check_path:  login_check 
    login_path:  login
```

I can see the recaptcha in login form but it is not validating during submission.

**Please help!**

Answer (score 0):

for login you need to basically have your own authentication provider since the form is handled by a special symfony process where only username and password are taken into account.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

Comment: Ok let me try. Thanks for the answer :)