# How to override Symfony2 Login for captcha control?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

First of all;

[Adding Captcha to Symfony2 Login Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788828/adding-captcha-to-symfony2-login-page)

I saw above conversation but this not exactly what i want. I just want to check if captcha is false right before authentication.

And no, i don't want to use a bundle for this.

**I need to know, when symfony2 does security login events?**

Diagram:

Login form submit -> check captcha -> check parameters -> do authentication.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get it work with below.

```
<?php

namespace CS\UserBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

class LoginListener
{
    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $captcha = $request->request->get('captcha');

        if(!empty($captcha) && $captcha !== $request->getSession()->get('captcha')) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException('Doğrulama Kodu Yanlış!');
        }
    }
}
```

Service (yml)

```
services:
  cs_user.login_listener:
      class: CS\UserBundle\Listener\LoginListener
      tags:
          - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login }
```

Comment: Hi, it is used to check captcha after login check. So, how can i check captcha before login?

Comment: @r_canser_yanbakan Thank you for sharing. But, at first sight I can tell you the `if` test is weak .. What if `$captcha` is actually empty ? like an empty string !? `if` content will not execute because `!empty()` part will return false, which means your form is not protected at all !! Test should fail if either $captcha isn't set or different from solution. At least `!` operator has to be removed imo `:/`.