# Symfony 3.4 Custom Authentication Listener

Tags: authentication, recaptcha, symfony3.x

I have implemented a login form manually in Twig and I am using the default authentication provided by Symfony 3.4 (based on username and password). Users are stored in a database, therefore I have an Entity which extends AdvancedUserInterface. I am using neither FOSUserBundle nor form builder. Just a simple form. It actually works.

The problem is that I want to integrate Google reCAPTCHA in the login process. I know how to check if the captcha is valid and implemented a custom AuthenticationListener (let's call it MyAuthenticationListener).

I know that Symfony uses UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener as its default listener. The problem is that I could not find a way to change the used listener to that I have implemented.

It seems that in Symfony2 it was as easy as adding the following line in the config.yml:

```
parameters:
   security.authentication.listener.form.class: 
       MyBundle\EventListener\MyAuthenticationListener
```

However, I cannot find a way for Symfony3. Any suggestions?
I also tried to find a specific bundle for Symfony3, but I actually could not find anything that is correctly integrated with Symfony Security, allowing me to use the recaptcha in a login form.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your question may be answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50800993/7408561

The solution is based on a custom-listener triggered by **SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN**. That event is fired after verification of credentials but before redirecting to **default_target_path** defined in security.yml. At this position you can verify the request parameter **g-recaptcha-response** by calling the google recaptcha api with the corresponding secret.

If the verification fails you can throw an exception and you will be redirected to the login page.