# Symfony2 : Pre Login event before specific provider

Tags: symfony

**Security.yml**

```
    providers:
        multiples:
            chain:
                providers: [db, ldap]
```

I would like to be able to run a pre-login check before the user is authenticated via the `db` provider only and not authenticating before any provider, does anyone know if this is possible (and how to do so) with Symfony 2.2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406001/is-there-any-sort-of-pre-login-event-or-similar