# Symfony2 - Intercepting request before form_login with EventListener

Tags: symfony

I have a `kernel.request` event listener service that modifies `request` however it is not executed for post requests handled by `form_login`. How can I manage to intercept requests before `SecurityBundle`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406001/is-there-any-sort-of-pre-login-event-or-similar

Answer (score 1):

Though never tried that, but maybe priority attribute can help

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

> There is an additional tag option priority that is optional and defaults to 0. 
>   This value can be from -255 to 255, and the listeners will be executed in the order 
>   of their priority (highest to lowest). This is useful when you need to guarantee that 
>   one listener is executed before another.

The Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall seems to subscribe to kernel.request with priority 8 so anything greater than that should work.

So, try it like this

```
# config.yml
services:
    kernel.listener.your_listener_name:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\AcmeRequestListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: 100 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it and let you know then.