# What is the listener called after login ?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I need to find a user in a webservice, so I need to modify the default Symfony Security  Listener.
I am using FOSUserBundle in my project.

I have found the Listener LastLoginListener that's fine I will need to modify this one too but first I need to find the code who is looking for the user login, password ect ...

I need to do something like this :
Do a request at a webservice : If User is found there, I update my own User with new informations and I login this User.

Have any idea what I need to modify ?

Sorry for my bad english, not my native language.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8425831/3675759  or maybe you need only `onSecurityInteractiveLogin`

Comment: Nice, exactly what I needed ! Thank you