# Symfony Block login if too many attempts

Tags: php, session, authentication, symfony

for learning purposes i'm trying to block login page if a user (robot or what it is) does too many attempts. I know i should use a (re)captcha but i'm studying symfony and i'm trying hard to understand its mechanism.

I thought to use a Event Listener to intercept the login request but i used a Session variable and it ends in a "Too many redirect" error

```
class BlockLoginListener {

    private $attempt;
    private $router;


    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session, RouterInterface $router){
        $this->attempt = $session->get(LoginAttempt::LOGIN_ATTEMPT, null);
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event){

        if ($event->getRequestType() !== \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST) {
            return;
        }

        if(null !== $this->attempt){
            if($this->attempt->isLocked()){
                $message = sprintf('Too much attempts, your account has been locked for %d minutes', $this->attempt->getLockInterva());

                $url = $this->router->generate("test",array("message" => $message));

                //$event->stopPropagation();
                $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));

            }
        }

    }
}
```

If i remove the attempt session variable at the end of the check it will perform just one redirect but the user will be able to access the login just with a new request as the attempt variable was deleted form session.

So, is there a way to block the login page using a session o or a entity based check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$this->attempt->isLocked()` returns `true`, you always redirect all requests to route *test*. That's where your *Too many redirects* error comes from.

This could be handled by implementing/overriding a more specific event listener, see:

[Is there any sort of "pre login" event or similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406001/is-there-any-sort-of-pre-login-event-or-similar)

Comment: Thank you! This is what i was looking for.