# How to make some security checks before the user will be granted to log-in (pre-login)?

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

According to this "Old" article [Is there any sort of "pre login" event or similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406001/is-there-any-sort-of-pre-login-event-or-similar) I can extend UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener to add some code pre-login.

In symfony3 seems that there's no `security.authentication.listener.form.class` parameter, so how can I reach the same result without changing symfony `security_listener.xml` config file?

Comment: read this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#services-configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform some pre/post-login checks (that means before/after the user authentication) one of the most simple and flexible solutions, offered by the Symfony framework, is to learn [How to Create and Enable Custom User Checkers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_checkers.html).

If you need more control and flexibility the best option is to learn [How to Create a Custom Authentication System with Guard](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html).
Take a look at the simple implementation example below:

**security.yml**

```
    firewall_name:
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - service_name_for_guard_authenticator
            entry_point: service_name_for_guard_authenticator <-- important to add a default one (as described in the docs) if you have many custom authenticators (facebook...)
```

**service.xml**

```
<service id="service_name_for_guard_authenticator"
         class="AppBundle\ExampleFolderName\YourGuardAuthClassName">
     <argument type="service" id="router"/>        
     <argument type="service" id="security.password_encoder"/>
</service>
```

**YourGuardAuthClassName.php**

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\AbstractGuardAuthenticator;
use use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder;

class YourGuardAuthClassName extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{
    private $router;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(
        Router              $router,
        UserPasswordEncoder $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->router          = $router;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('your_user_login_route_name'));

        return $response;
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        # CHECK IF IT'S THE CHECK LOGIN ROUTE
        if ($request->attributes->get('_route') !== 'your_user_login_route_name'
            || !$request->isMethod('POST')) {
            return null;
        }
        # GRAB ALL REQUEST PARAMETERS
        $params = $request->request->all();
        # SET LOGIN CREDENTIALS
        return array(
            'email'    => $params['email'],
            'password' => $params['password'],
        );
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $email = $credentials['email'];
        $user  = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($email);
        if (! $user){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException();
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        # YOU CAN ADD YOUR CHECKS HERE!
        if (! $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password'])) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        # OYU CAN ALSO USE THE EXCEPTIONS TO ADD A FLASH MESSAGE (YOU HAVE TO INJECT YOUR OWN FLASH MESSAGE SERVICE!) 
        if ($exception instanceof UsernameNotFoundException){
            $this->flashMessage->error('user.login.exception.credentials_invalid');
        }
        if ($exception instanceof BadCredentialsException){
            $this->flashMessage->error('user.login.exception.credentials_invalid');
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('your_user_login_route_name'));
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('your_success_login_route_name'));
    }

    public function supportsRememberMe()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need control before user credentials are checked.

Comment: @JackSkeletron Then you can perform your checks in the `checkPreAuth` method. You are using the "guard" system (very useful when you need specific customizations) or the default one?

Comment: Default one. Should I use guard? http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html

Comment: @JackSkeletron Yes, "Guard" simplify all the authentication process and allows you a fine grained control over it. If you need a simple implementation example would be better if you update your question adding a bit of context.

Comment: @JackSkeletron I added a simple example using "Guard" to show you how to implement a basic login system. Let me know if this suit your main needs. (PS: I will see your answer in 2 hours)