# Symfony - Pre login event listener

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, oauth

I need to do some actions before the login process/at the beginning of the login process. Is there any pre login event or how can I implement it?

I'am using Symfony3 and I have a form login and OAuth login (HWIOAuthBundle).

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406001/is-there-any-sort-of-pre-login-event-or-similar), but it doesn't work with OAuth login. Or how can I implement it for OAuth login too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally all login stuff in symfony is executed by a listener to the `kernel.request` event, mostly within the `Firewall` listener of the Symfony security component. I did not use the HWIOAuthBundle bundle yet, but it seems it also just uses the Symfony Security component.

If you just want to execute certain actions before the login/authentication happens, you only need to register an event listener to the `kernel.request` with a higher priority than the `Firewall` listener.

You can do that as described in the Symfony docs ([Events and Event Listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html)). First create your Event listener class in `src/AppBundle/EventListener/YourListener.php`:

```php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class YourListener
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Then register your service in your `app/config/services.yml` file:

```
services:
    AppBundle\EventListener\YourListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, priority: 9 }
```

According to [this page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html) the Firewall has a priority of 8. So the priority of your event listener should be higher than that to be executed before the login happens (I used 9 in the example above).

Comment: It may solve my problem, but how can I force it to run only before the authentication? Now it's running in every request.

Comment: The `Firewall` listener is also executed on every request. What exactly are you trying to do (i.e. what are the actions you want to perform before login)?

Comment: I log some actions about the non-logged user with session id, and I want to fill up these records with the logged user, but the problem is the session id will be changed after the authentication.

Comment: You could register one listener as I described in my answer to only store the session id in the `$request->attributes` parameter bag, so you can access it later and create an additional listener to the `security.authentication.success` event to do the actual logging after the successful login.